# I'm having trouble escaping a unicode reference in JavaDoc

Tags: unicode, javadoc

I want to put an example in JavaDoc:

```
/***
 * This will filter out symbols like:
 * Waving White Flag U+1F3F3 {@literal "\uD83C\uDFF3"} in Miscellaneous Symbos and Pictographs.
 * …
 */
```

I've tried `@code`, `@literal`, and `<pre>` none of which seem to keep it, but it'd be nice if it was legible both in the doc and source. I also can't seem to put `"&#92;uD83C&#92;uDFF3"` into those for the fixed width rendering.

I'd like it to read like:

> This will filter out symbols like: Waving White Flag U+1F3F3 `"\uD83C\uDFF3"` in Miscellaneous Symbos and Pictographs. …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the backslash as `\u005C` to hijack the unwanted encoding, and use `<code></code>`:

```
/**
 * This will filter out symbols like:
 * Waving White Flag U+1F3F3 <code>"\u005CuD83C\u005CuDFF3"</code> in Miscellaneous Symbos and Pictographs.
 * …
 */
```

Comment: That works, though it's harder for someone reading the source to know what that means.